# Get passed variable name as string

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that adds data to a PHP session array.  I want to dynamically create the Key of the array item as the variable name, and set the value of said key to that variables value.  My example code so far:

```
$foo = 'bar';
addHookpointVar($foo);

function addHookpointVar($var) {
    $_SESSION['HOOKPOINT']['foo'] = $var;
}
```

Is there a method in PHP to get a string representation of a variable, such that my $_SESSION['HOOKPOINT']['VAR'] will be set to the name of the variable passed in?

All the methods I have found involve looping through every variable in the $_GLOBALS

Comment: you just have to pass the name as 2nd argument.

Comment: @AziBaloch Yes, I knew that was an option but thank you for pointing that out.  This question was to specifically see if there are methods to use a variables name as a string.  I'm trying to write a function to do a lot of generic-manipulations where I am not required to hard-code every variable name into the function call

Comment: @ArbraCadaver is posted exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$foo = 'bar';
addHookpointVar(compact('foo'));

function addHookpointVar($var) {
    list($key, $val) = each($var);
    $_SESSION['HOOKPOINT'][$key] = $val;
}
```

Or maybe cleaner for the function:

```
function addHookpointVar($var) {
    $_SESSION['HOOKPOINT'] = array_merge($_SESSION['HOOKPOINT'], $var);
}
```

However, I would probably just use an array `$hp['foo'] = 'bar';` and then you can pass `$hp` into the function.

Comment: This is a very nice / clean solution.  I was hoping to keep it generic enough that I would be able to use a variable name as a string (so I can dynamically call the function on loops and such), but this solution is still very helpful.  From the looks of it, the variable name as string is likely not possible.  I'm going to leave the question open for a little while, but I'll accept this answer if nothing along those other lines comes in :) +1

Comment: I thought he did grab the var name as string though? :/
`compact('foo')` created an associative array where it's then represented by $var in the scope of the function and $key would be the var name (foo in this case) would it not ?

Comment: Kind of.  It still requires putting in a string representation instead of directly passing a variable into it (as I mentioned, would be useful when inside of loops, etc.), which is mainly what I was hoping to accomplish.  It definitely seems like this is the closest to a solution that can be accomplished, though so I'm accepting the answer

Answer (score -1):

I was also looking for a solution to convert a variable name as string.
Having not found the correct answer, I created a function for this problem.

```
<?php
function func(&$variable) {
    $backupValue = $variable;
    $variable = uniqid();
    foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($key) && $value == $variable) {
            $variable = $backupValue;
            return $key;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception('error number xx');
}

$test1 = "This is a test";
$test2 = 'This is a second test';
$test3 = 'This is a second test';

$array = [];

$array[func($test1)] = $test1;
$array[func($test2)] = $test2;
$array[func($test3)] = $test3;

var_dump($array);
?>
```

(Also available [on Github](https://github.com/nico2am/tools/blob/master/tool1.php).)

Comment: While the link may answer the question, links change, so Stack Overflow prefers to not depend on them. [It would be better](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I didn't know, sorry! Edited!